# Em desenvolvimento web java, qual melhor prática de armazenagem de imagens? Em banco de dados ou pastas de imagens?

Tags: java, banco-de-dados, imagem, java-ee, design-pattern

Em uma aplicação Java Web, qual melhor forma de armazenar imagens? Armazenar em banco de dados ou em pastas de imagens e no banco usar caminhos pra essas imagens?  E como faria isso?

Pensando em usar gravar no banco de dados, usaria o `Base64` do java, para uma manipulação futura.

Comment: Eu fiz uma teste uma vez com banco, tive o problema de lentidão na hora de executar a chamada das querys com muitos dados, ai tive que externalizar o Blob para uma tabela a parte da tabela de dados da image, depois disso eu sempre uso salvamento externo, facilita na recuperação de dados, e se for imagem, facilita o carregamento dela, pois vc vai mandar os componentes chamar a url que vc vai mandar como atributo, e fica até mais facil pra gerenciar migração se vc dividir o contexto de url de arquivo  e servidor

Comment: @WeslleyBarbosa tava pesando em usar no banco de dados para a imagem a String Base64

Comment: Não é uma boa pratica, até pq vc vai ter que carregar uma lista de objetos que contem uma string gigantesca do base64, e se por ventura uma componente não suportar, vc vai precisar fazer conversão, se vc enviar somente a url, a pagina vai poder carregar as informações primeiro e fazer uma chamada independente para carregar a imagem da url